# While loop for multipule conditions

Tags: java, while-loop, bluej

just mainly looking for the last line where the while loop is because im making the game Mastermind in my class and i want to keep the guessing going while the guess's do not equal the secretcode. Thanks

```
        if (guess1 == secretcode) {
            System.out.print (" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
        }
        if (guess2 == secretcode1) {
            System.out.print (" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
        }
        if (guess3 == secretcode2) {
            System.out.print (" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
        }
        if (guess4 == secretcode3) {
            System.out.print (" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
        }
         do 
         {
             System.out.println ("Keep guessing you have not won yet!");
             System.out.println ("What is the number one peg in my code???");
        guess1 = Guess.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("What is the number two peg in my code???");
        guess2 = Guess.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("What is the number three peg in my code???");
        guess3 = Guess.nextInt();
        System.out.println ("What is the number four peg in my code???");
        guess4 = Guess.nextInt();
    }
     while  (guess1 != secretcode), (guess2 != secretcode1), (guess3 != secretcode2), (guess4 != secretcode3);
```

Comment: Have you tried looking up how to make a while loop? I just did a quick search and found this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of commas, use the `&&` (AND) operator

```
do{
    //code to iterate here
}
while ( (guess1 != secretcode) && (guess2 != secretcode1) 
        && (guess3 != secretcode2) && (guess4 != secretcode3) );
```

Take note of the extra set of parentheses I added. It's good to keep the ones you already had, for readability's sake.

---

As Jesper commented below, you can do the same for your `if` statements. Clears up lots of space.

```
if ( (guess1 == secretcode) && (guess2 == secretcode1) 
    && (guess3 == secretcode2) && (guess4 == secretcode3) ) {

    System.out.print (" You have guessed one correctly in the right spot!");
}
do {
    //code to iterate here
} while (condition)
```

Comment: And you can use `&&` also for the `if` statements, so that you don't have to copy and paste everything 4 times.

Comment: @Jesper, definitely. Good advice for OP, I will include that in my answer.

Comment: the `do` is missing too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the AND Operator `&&`

```
while  (guess1 != secretcode && guess2 != secretcode1 && guess3 != secretcode2 && guess4 != secretcode3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine conditions with [conditional operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) AND (`&&`), OR (`||`):

```
do {
    ... loop contents ...
} while(guess1 != secretcode &&
        guess2 != secretcode1 &&
        guess3 != secretcode2 &&
        guess4 != secretcode3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `&&` Operator, it allows you to check for multiple conditions. 
Code:

```
do {
//loop body
} while(guess1 != secretcode && guess2 != secretcode1 &&  guess3 !=secretcode2 &&  guess4 != secretcode3);
```

Note: if you use && then all conditions need to be true for the loop to execute. If you want the loop to execute when only one condition is true use `||`